# Paste content from Excel to Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, google-chrome, safari

I am currently dealing with an issue of copying multiple rows of one column from Excel (on macOS) to the browser. I am receiving an `event` and access the copied content like this: `event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');`

After I received the content, I want to split them with various matchers like this:

```
const separators = [',', ';', '\\(', '\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\?', '\n', '\t'];
return data.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g')).map(d => d.trim());
```

This works perfectly in Firefox but it does not in latest Chrome and Safari. I thought, you would match new rows with `\n` or `\t`. My goal is to retrieve an array of values per line. I imagine this has something to do with special line endings of Excel because when using Numbers from Apple everything works perfectly.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to add a CR, **carriage return**, symbol (it is the default line break style in MS Office documents). Also, `String#split` method does not require the use of the `g` global modifier with the regex passed as an argument, as this method behavior is like that by default.

Use

```
const separators = [',', ';', '\\(', '\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\?', '\n', '\r'];
return data.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'))).map(d => d.trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got this working.

```
    /*
     * Chrome and Safari seem to treat new lines pasted from Excel like an Enter press.
     * Enter has a CharCode of 13, so checking if this string contains CharCode 13 is sufficient.
     * If the string contains a CharCode 13, we split the string after every CharCode 13.
     * And kids, that's how I made pasting from Excel possible (HIMYM voice)
     */

    const enterCharCode = String.fromCharCode(13);

    if (data.includes(enterCharCode)) {
        return data.split(enterCharCode);
    }

    const separators = [',', ';', '\\(', '\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\?', '\n'];
    return data.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g')).map(d => d.trim());
```

Comment: All you need then is to add `\r`: `const separators = [',', ';', '\\(', '\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\?', '\n', '\t', '\r'];`. Also, you do not need the `'g'`  modifier, it is the default behavior for `split`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, that's even better! Thank you 